# IntelliJ: Resolve paths in subfolders from source root instead of relative

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Let's say I have the following project structure:

```
webapp
- app/
  - index.html
  - main/
    - some.html
    - other.js
  - img/
    - img.svg
  - lib/
    - lib.js
```

I have the `app` folder marked as a source root in IntelliJ. That means the references from `index.html` to `lib/lib.js` and `main/other.js` will resolve fine. However, the reference to `img/img.svg` in `main/some.html` does not resolve, because IntelliJ thinks it's a relative path, and will only look in `main/img/img.svg`.

How do I tell IntelliJ that paths in files in subfolders of the source root, should be resolved relative to the root, instead of relative to the subfolder?

Comment: But that is not going to work in browser neither, right? The way you describe seems to be absolute path - should start with /

Comment: It does work in browser. Angular just loads the templates from the subfolder, (effectively) includes them in the index, and they all go from there.

Comment: Strange, can you provide a working example on plunker? https://plnkr.co/